# Submodule intra-dependencies in Julia

Tags: julia, dependency-management

I'm trying to create a package with the following layout:

```
MyPkg
├── MyPkg.jl
├── Foo
│   ├── Foo.jl
│   └── another_file.jl
└── Bar
    ├── Bar.jl
    └── yet_another_file.jl
```

My main package module looks something like this:

```
# MyPkg.jl
module Pkg

include("./Foo/Foo.jl")
using .Foo: FooStuffA, FooStuffB
export FooStuffA, FooStuffB

include("./Bar/Bar.jl")
using .Bar: BarStruct, BarStuffC, BarStuffD
export BarStruct, BarStuffC, BarStuffD

end
```

The problem arises when `Foo` needs a type (specifically a `struct`) defined in `Bar` in some function arguments. I'm not sure how to import this type. I've tried seemingly all combinations of `include("../Bar/Bar.jl")`, `using Bar/.Bar/..Bar`, inside the `Foo` submodule, outside the submodule, etc.

```
# Foo.jl
module Foo

# what am I missing here?

function print_bar_struct(bar::BarStruct)
    @show bar
end

end
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
# MyPkg.jl
module MyPkg
include("./Bar/Bar.jl")
using .Bar: BarStruct, BarStuffC, BarStuffD
export BarStruct, BarStuffC, BarStuffD

include("./Foo/Foo.jl")
using .Foo: FooStuffA, FooStuffB
export FooStuffA, FooStuffB
end
```

```
# Foo.jl
module Foo

using ..MyPkg: BarStruct

function print_bar_struct(bar::BarStruct)
    @show bar
end

end
```

Explanation: Remember that include statements are essentially copying+pasting the code from the source file into the module at the given line. So by the time the compiler is looking at the references for all of the symbols (reading from the top of the file to the bottom), at the point where `include("./Foo/Foo.jl")` occurs, it needs to know that BarStruct exists and is accessible in the current module (i.e., MyPkg), which it is in this rearranged layout.

So by looking just at this first half of `MyPkg`

```
# MyPkg.jl
module MyPkg
include("./Bar/Bar.jl")
using .Bar: BarStruct, BarStuffC, BarStuffD
export BarStruct, BarStuffC, BarStuffD
```

by the time the compiler reaches the last line here, `BarStruct`, `BarStuffC`, `BarStuffD` are the symbols brought into the `MyPkg` namespace (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Summary-of-module-usage-1).

When we reach the `include("./Foo/Foo.jl")` line (aka copying + pasting this source file into the current module at this point), we need to reference `BarStruct` in the parent namespace of this module, i.e., `..BarStruct`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! This makes total sense when you remember Julia is still an interpreted language, not a compiled language like C/C++.

Comment: Actually, I needed to do: `using ..MyPkg: BarStruct`. Perhaps you could update your answer if you agree that this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried referencing the struct with its module.struct full name, as in Bar.BarStruct?

With structures and enums, the export function seems to not work as well as with function names, but using the Module.Struct type syntax often works.